# repeated measure ANOVA with non-consecutive repeats

Tags: time-series, anova, repeated-measures

I have a somewhat of a repeated measure setup but wanted to check if repeated measure 1-way anova can be applied here (assuming underlying assumptions of normality, sphericity etc are met).

Situation: time series data of N subjects self-reporting a binary variable (yes/no), and also providing a continuous measure X with every self report.

Hypothesis: measure X is different on days with "yes" reports compared to days with "No" reports.

analysis idea: For each subject, separately average measure X for "yes" days and "no" days. X is a repeated measure for each subject. Run a 1-way repeated measure ANOVA.

My main question is: if the repeated measure is not consecutively repeated (yes and no days can be in any sequence), seems like it shouldn't matter?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking when you say "seems like it shouldn't matter". What shouldn't matter? Whether you use repeated measures methods or not? If that's the case then irrespective f when the measures are collected it is still likely that measures from the same individual will be more correlated than those from another individual, breaking the independence assumption.

Comment: Maybe you're mixing two concepts of repeated-measures: time-series and subject correlation? So you mean: if I break the time-series, then is not a repeated-mesures? As @Martyn says, even when there is no time-series involved, observations coming from the same subject are expected to show higher correlation than two observations from different subjects. So it is still a within-subjects design. [though I think a more elegant statistical design would assess if x can predict No-Yes, as a logistic regression in a within-subject design (a generalized linear mixed model)]

Comment: yes, apologies for lack of clarity. Question was should it matter for repeated measure ANOVA if the repeats are non-consecutive in time? Basically the time sequence (or trial) of the independent variable for a single user could look something like (Yes, No, No, Yes, No, No, Yes, Yes), and their dependent variable or repeated measure would be (X1,X2,X3,...,X8). In my description I  collapse(=average) the repeated measures to just two: Yes and No trials. You're correct that the two are still more correlated.

Comment: thx @FairMiles, that is ultimately the goal, but data set is still too small and we're at the exploratory phase

Comment: @Corib: note that you can try a much simpler approach, when  for each subject you average X on "yes" days and on "no" days, obtaining two values for each subject, and then run a paired t-test on those values. If that works (i.e. shows significance difference), why bother with anything more complicated?